# How to undeploy a .war with Jenkins?

Tags: maven, selenium, tomcat, jenkins, automated-tests

we are working on our Selenium Grid Setup. 
We did it like this:
We got 2x Jenkins Jobs and 2x Tomcats.
We are using Maven!

1. First Jenkins Job deploys the application (to test) on a tomcat. This job got a post action where the second job is triggered. (of course with ignored testing)
2. Second Jenkins Job tests the application deployed on the first tomcat and if its successful it will deploy the application on the second and final Tomcat.

Now we need to undeploy the application on the first Tomcat if its deployed on the second one.

Is there any option to integrate this in the second Jenkins Job?

It would be nice if you could give me some advice.

Thank you
-T

Comment: Why do you use 2 jenkins jobs? you could do the same thing with only one job. How do you deploy the webapps? Are deployed in the same machine where is execute jenkins?

Comment: Hello Davide, thank you for your answer. How is it possible to do all this in only one job? We are at the start with setting up our Selenium setup. At the moment we run 2x different VMs. 1. Tomcat for test deploy 2. Selenium Grid Hub + Node, Jenkins and the Tomcat for the final deploy.

Comment: fwiw I think it makes sense to have this separated. If one job does too much you can have some pretty fragile stuff in there and it's hard to configure. Now I'm not totally sure what you mean by undeploy... You could just stop tomcat, but do you want to also remove the files for some reason? You could have a step that runs a script to clean the files, but I don't totally understand the necessity of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the way to deploy and undeploy on Tomcat in an automated fashion is to use the [Maven Tomcat plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html). Disregard the fact that it seems to be only for Tomcat version 7 - it will work the same for 7+.

Behind the scenes, this plugin utilizes the [Tomcat manager REST API](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

Your Jenkins commands would probably go like:

1. `mvn tomcat7:deploy` on first server
2. If the deploy and startup is successful, you'll get a verifiable response that looks like: "`OK - Deployed application at context path /foo`" (and likely the relative error code)

   - You could also write a curl and parse command
     for the manager command at `http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list`
     to check if the application deployed as a sanity check
3. If it deployed

   - Do a `mvn tomcat7:deploy` on the second server and
   - Do a `mvn tomcat7:undeploy` on
     the first server.

Just for all of the information to be here, the basic maven configuration for this plugin is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/myAppContextPath</path>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```